# How to label my Lidar data based on Kitti format?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, point-clouds, lidar, kitti

I am using Ouster Lidar on Ubuntu 22.04 for my project. I want to use deep learning method (Pointpillars method using python codes) for 3D object detection on point cloud data. All deep learning examples are based on Kitti dataset/label format. The Kitti labels are saved on *.txt files and each object's label contains 15 numbers.
Is there any annotation software to label my dataset based on Kitti format with different class names?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Best,

Abbas

Answer (score 0):

This is a tool for creating 3D instance segmentation annotations for the KITTI object detection dataset. The code loads in the KITTI bounding box object annotations and gives points initial labels based on whether they fall within a ground truth bounding box. The user then cleans up the annotations using a point cloud viewer GUI.

https://github.com/brian-h-wang/kitti-3d-annotator

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. After running the software, it just prints "Annotating frame 29..." without any error on anaconda shell and does not show me anything. I think it might because of my OS system (Ubuntu 22.04). Any suggestion?

Comment: I would recommend filing an issue on their github repo or contacting the people who implemented the code. They probably know best.